# Sending data from servlet to android application with JSON

Tags: android, json, servlets, httpclient

Good night,

I'm trying to send from a servlet written in Java data name in a JSON to an application in Android.

Not that I'm doing wrong but when it comes to mobile text comes a strange text.

Below I describe the code:

servlet:

```
if (opcion.equals("4")){//Devolver nombre, apellidos y DNI de Usuario

        String usuario = request.getParameter("login");
        Usuario user = facade.getUsuarioByLogin(usuario);

        String nombre= user.getNombre();
        String apellidos = user.getApellidos();
        String dni = user.getDni();

        System.out.println("El valor de Nombre es"+nombre);


        response.setContentType("application/json");

        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( nombre );

        //System.out.println("El valor de json"+json.toString());
        out.println(json);

        out.close();
    }
```

Piece of Android application code that gets the JSON (I ignored the try catch to make the code more readable):

```
HttpClient cliente = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost (url.toString());


    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    List<NameValuePair> elementos = ele;


        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(elementos));

    HttpResponse respuesta = null;

        respuesta = cliente.execute(post);


    Log.i("Prueba", "El valor de respuesta es "+respuesta.toString());
```

I thought that respuesta should have the JSON that servlet sends me but it returns a  text which does not contain the name

Do you see something you do wrong?

Greetings and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to pass in the `ResponseHandler` into the `HttpClient#exeucte()` method.

Replace

```
HttpResponse respuesta = null;
respuesta = cliente.execute(post);
Log.i("Prueba", "El valor de respuesta es "+respuesta.toString());
```

by

```
String respuesta = cliente.execute(post, handler);
Log.i("Prueba", "El valor de respuesta es " + respuesta);
```